# How to integrate laravel template with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I have created my website in Laravel 5 with template integrated in it. Now I want to add chat feature in my website, so I decided to use Vue.js. The problem is that when I setup Vue.js in my project, the page template of that page in which vue.js is used is not working. I mean that all the css and js file of laravel getting mess up. Page looks horrible.
How Can I use my existing template with Vue.js?

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL('css/style.css?version=2') }}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/ionicons.min.css') }}" />
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
        <div id="custom-search-input">
           <div class="input-group col-md-12">
              <input type="text" class="  search-query form-control" placeholder="Conversation" />
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
              <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
              </button>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="app">
            <example-component></example-component>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown all_conversation">
           <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           <i class="fa fa-weixin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           All Conversations
           <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
           </button>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
              <li><a href="#"> All Conversation </a>  <ul class="sub_menu_ list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="#"> All Conversation </a> </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
           </ul>
           </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

ExampleComponent.vue

```
    <template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card card-default">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

[Console warnings and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDufn.png)

Comment: You basically write your Vue component(s), register them so they can be loaded and add them to the page you want them on. Any code you want to share?

Comment: Yes... @kerbholz

Comment: My style.css code is not making any effect on my page. @kerbholz

Comment: Does it apply `style.css` without the `<example-component>`? Any warnings/errors in your browser console? Have you altered anything in the component? Is the component rendered at all?

Comment: Yes, it apply style.css without loading app.css and app.js file.           Nothing altered in the component.

Comment: Added example component and console errors in questions. Please refer and provide some solution. Thanks @kerbholz

Comment: Thanks for the codes. Hm, at a loss here. I just set up a fresh Laravel5.6 installation with the example component and as expected, it works like a charm. I used `layouts/app.blade.php`, a custom `_style.scss` imported in `app.scss` and `npm run watch` to compile all assets. Maybe try that .scss approach instead of linking to your `style.css`. Other than that I can't help any further, sorry.

Comment: Ok. I found that if I don't add app.css file path, then my custom css is loading properly. Is that a good way to use app.js file and not to use app.css file? @kerbholz

Comment: `app.js` and `app.css` are different things and "should" both be used. Any additional/custom CSS you need can either be in `app.scss` or in a seperate .scss file and then be imported in `app.scss`. This way all your CSS gets managed by webpack/mix and can for example be minified on your production server when running `npm run production`.